# Combine THREE.MeshFaceMaterial and THREE.BackSide?

Tags: three.js

Using three.js v56:

I have an array of textures called `materialArray`, then I create

```
var cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materialArray );
```

However, I would like this texture to be reversed; for a "normal" material called `simpleMaterial`, one would enter:

```
simpleMaterial.side = THREE.BackSide;
```

Alas, this has no effect in this case; the material is still displayed on the "front" side.
So, how can the texture be set to the backside when working with an array of textures as in MeshFaceMaterial?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`materialArray` needs to be an array of materials, not an array of textures.

You must set the `side` property to  `THREE.BackSide` for each material in the material array that you want flipped.

three.js r.56

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped -- I do have an array of materials, each built using a texture -- and of course that's where I needed to change the value of side. I ended up using a for loop, materialArray[i].side = THREE.BackSide, and life is good again! Many thanks :)